# plus plus operator not working in php

Tags: php

```
<?php 
$qry = mysql_query("select branch from branches");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($qry)) {
        $branch = $row['branch'];
        $i=1;
?>
     <div class="dropdown">
        <input type="checkbox" id="drop<?php echo $i; ?>" />
        <label for="drop<?php echo $i++; ?>" class="dropdown_button"><?php echo "$branch"; ?><span class="arrow"></span></label>
        <ul class="dropdown_content">

        <?php
            $qry1 = mysql_query("select sub_dir from `$branch`");
            while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($qry1)) {
                $sub_topic = $row1['sub_dir'];
        ?>
            <li><a href="#"><?php echo "$sub_topic"; ?></a></li>                                                           
           <?php 
            }
           ?>
        </ul>

    </div>
<?php }?>
```

In line number 9, you can see, inside 'label' tag, I am trying to increment the variable '$i' but of no use because at every call to next row from the table, the value of '$i' remains same i.e. '1'. Where I am doing wrong.
Another question: Is it possible to create id's at run time as I did in line 8, i.e 'drop1, drop2,...'. May be its foolish way of doing something but I am trying new things.

Comment: try to set your $i=1; before loop start

Comment: oops!!! yaa.. thanku.. just a silly mistake..

Comment: there is no problem while creating ids at run time?

Comment: check view source i can suggest your showing code error it's depend on you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$i` initialization will be before the while loop

```
$i=1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($qry)) {
    $branch = $row['branch'];
```

Answer (score 0):

**Initialize $i before the loop begin**

```
$i=1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($qry)) {
    //while loop block
}
```